# Suspend execution until object value is set through LiveData

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata, kotlin-coroutines

I'm working with a third party SDK which has a LiveData object I need to observe in order to set the value of a custom object of mine:

```
    fun setValueAndDoSomething(activity: FragmentActivity) {
        var myCustomObject: MyCustomObject? = null
        sdkComponent.observe(activity, Observer { sdkResult ->
            myCustomObject = MyCustomObject(sdkResult)
        })
        
        // Wait until myCustomObject is not null
        myCustomObject.doSomething()
    }
```

I want to wait until the SDK LiveData's callback is triggered, so that myCustomObject is not null, to proceed with the rest of the execution. How can I achieve that using Kotlin Coroutines?

Comment: Why do you need to use coroutine here? Why not just call `doSomething` right after object creation in the observer callback? And actually, in order to wait for the object to be not null, the library has to return a `Deferred` object.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to await a result, your function must be suspendable. Use `suspendCoroutine` to get a continuation and resume it from the callback:

```
suspend fun setValueAndDoSomething(activity: FragmentActivity) {
    val myCustomObject = suspendCoroutine<MyCustomObject> { cont ->
        sdkComponent.observe(activity, Observer { sdkResult ->
            cont.resume(MyCustomObject(sdkResult))
        })
    }
    myCustomObject.doSomething()
}
```

To be able to call this, you'll have to `launch` a coroutine.